# How to define grid margins for each breakpoint when semantically building a Foundation XY-grid

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I want to build a grid using the mixins for XY-grid in Zurb Foundation 6.6, but I run into problems when I want to set the negative margins for the grid itself only on specific breakpoints.

Using the mixin `xy-gutters()` creates margins for each breakpoint, and I cannot choose to use margins just for some of them.

In the example below I want breakpoint(medium) to have a cell without margin gutters.

How is this meant to be done?

```
.hero {
  &__container {
    @include xy-grid-container;
  }

  &__grid {
    @include xy-grid();

    // This generates gutter margins for all breakpoints so I cannot choose to have without gutters for some breakpoints
    @include xy-gutters(
      $gutter-type: margin,
      $gutter-position: right left,
      $negative: true
    );
  }

  &__cell {
    @include xy-cell($size: 4, $gutter-type: margin);

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
      @include xy-cell($size: 6, $gutter-type: none);
    }

    @include breakpoint(large) {
      @include xy-cell($size: 4, $gutter-type: margin);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the

```
@include xy-cell-gutters($gutters, $gutter-type, $gutter-position, $breakpoint, $vertical);
```

mixin on your `.cell`

Set gutters to a px or rem value or Sass map;